# Hovering over child and parent to trigger change

Tags: html, css, sass, hover, styling

I'm trying to make an input field with a button and custom sprite image inside of it.

> The input should change the border color and show the button with an
>   icon while hovering. Additionally while hovering both input and
>   button, the icon should be changed.

Right now the icon changes with input:focus while dismissing the border of the input.

If somebody can guide me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I came up so far:

HTML

```
<form class="b-editor-item col-3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="D" class="b-editor-d-input" />
  <button type="button" class="b-editor-button-delete">
       <div class="b-editor-icon-trash"></div>
  </button>
</form>
```

SCSS

```
input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.b-editor {
  &-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  &-button-delete {
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &-d-input {
    color: black;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-right: -3.25rem;
    height: 2rem;
  }

  &-icon-trash {
    background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1044597/trash.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -28px 0;
    background-size: 300%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 5px 2px;
  }

  &-d-input:hover + &-button-delete:hover > &-icon-trash,
  &-d-input:focus + &-button-delete:hover > &-icon-trash {
    background-position: -52px 0;
  }

  &-d-input + &-button-delete {
    display: none;
  }
  &-d-input:hover + &-button-delete,
  &-d-input:focus + &-button-delete,
  &-d-input:hover + &-button-delete:hover {
    display: block;
  }

  &-d-input:hover,
  &-d-input:hover + &-button-delete:hover {
    border: 1px solid #00c8aa !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want your icon be colored if you hover it?

Comment: Colored yes, but it's handled by moving a sprite image. Basically I need to trigger the rule on hover; while hovering the child and parent elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add these 2 rules:

```css
button.b-editor-button-delete:hover {
    display: block;
}

button.b-editor-button-delete:hover .b-editor-icon-trash {
    background-position: -52px 0;
}
```

Comment: The rules are working, all that is left to do is to make the border stay green instead of falling back to transparent. I'll play around with it until tomorrow before I mark the question as solved. If you have a suggestion on how to do that, you are more than free to check it at https://codepen.io/organyx/pen/LYENqVQ

Comment: This won't work as you expected. You will have to change your HTML nesting and then adjust your css

Comment: You are right, I have changed the nesting and simplified the rules. I was overcomplicating it.  Here's what I replaced it with https://codepen.io/organyx/pen/KKwMgZY